# How to getElementById for A Group of Elements with Similar ID's?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a task where I have to manipulate some data in input fields that have similar named and ID'd elements.

let's just say things like ID_1 ID_2 or SCH_name SCH_start SCH_end.  If I wanted to for example hide all those input fields based on their ID prefix is there something like a "contains" that would do that?

Comment: you can use queryselector

Comment: use classes and queryselector

Comment: [Locating DOM elements using selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) with making use of attribute selectors

Comment: @MarkBaijens There are no duplicate IDs in this question.

Comment: `var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName("input");` `for(var input of inputs) if(input.id.includes("SCH") && (input.id.indexOf("SCH")==0)) input.style.display="none";`.  This checks that "SCH" is in the id AND that it's at the beginning of it.  I'm sure there are easier ways to check that.  To undo the hiding: `input.style.display="";`

Answer (score 2):

Note: Maybe you should add classes to your element.

---

You can use `querySelectorAll`

```js
for(let elem of document.querySelectorAll("[id^=d]")){
  console.log(elem.id)
}
```

```html
<div id="d1">1</div>
<div id="d2">2</div>
<div id="d3">3</div>
<div id="w1">1</div>
<div id="w2">2</div>
<div id="w3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably an [Attribute selector (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

`[attr^=value]`

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is prefixed (preceded) by value.

So yours would be:

```
[id^="ID_"] {
}
```